# Ruby Types Error

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to replace a column in a large (4.6GB) csv file with a value from another file.  For example:

| id | name |

| 01 |  john

| id | address | phone |

| 01 | place | number

What I want is for 01 in the bottom table to be replaced with 'john'.

```
new = CSV.open("usage_new.csv", "w")
prog = CSV.read("programs.csv", encoding:"ASCII-8BIT")

CSV.foreach("Usage-fixed.csv", encoding:"ASCII-8BIT") do |row|
    for i in 0..prog.size
        if row[5] == prog[i][0]
            puts row[5] + " equals " + prog[i][1]
            new << [ row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + row[3] + row[4] + prog[i][1] + row[5] + row[6] + row[7] + row[8] + row[9] + row[10] + row[11] + row[12] + row[13] + row[14] + row[15] + row[16] + row[17] ]
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is i keep getting the following error:

```
blah.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from blah.rb:10:in `each'
    from blah.rb:10:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/mastelj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1717:in `each'
    from /home/mastelj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1120:in `block in foreach'
    from /home/mastelj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1266:in `open'
    from /home/mastelj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1119:in `foreach'
    from blah.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on what might cause something like this?

Edit: Line 11 (the offending line) is the line with the iff statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your for statement, you are going from `0` to `prog.size`.  You want to go from `0` to `prog.size - 1`.

You're getting the `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` for the last index which is the `prog.size`.

Please do the following:

```
for i in 0..prog.size-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `raw` is `nil` or `prog[i]` is `nil` for every iterations